# Copying files within C# issue

Tags: c#, copy

I am creating a project to do with some simple tasks to help my work.

The application is being made as a windows form in C#.
Everything seems to be fine other than one issue, the issue is that when copying files from a shared location to a local location, all of them work other than one.
the code is as follows:

```
private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = "Analyst's Name.txt";
            string fileName1 = "Group Name.txt";
            string fileName2 = "KB Number.txt";
            string fileName3 = "Return Notes.txt";
            string sourcePath = @"\\remote location";
            string targetPath = @"C:\SUPPORT\";

        string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
            string sourceFile1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName1);
            string sourceFile2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName2);
            string sourceFile3 = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName3);
        string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
            string destFile1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName1);
            string destFile2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName2);
            string destFile3 = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName3);
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
        }
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true); 
            System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile1, destFile1, true);
            System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile2, destFile2, true);
            System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile3, destFile3, true);
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
        {
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);
            foreach (string s in files)
            {
                fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
                destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                destFile1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName1);
                destFile2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName2);
                destFile3 = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName3);
                System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
                System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile1, true);
                System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile2, true);
                System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile3, true);
```

now the problem is that the return notes file that is locally on the C drive, is being copied but the data within it is showing as the analyst name data, the name of the file is correct, but the data inside is from a different file, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

Comment: sorry but the method work, do you mean i have to change the way that is written totally?

Comment: Why are you copying everything twice? And the second time - overwriting all files with whatever happens to be in the sourcePath?

Comment: so taking the if statement would work? i thought ide do that so i can confirm that the source path exists?

Comment: I would look at the variables in debugger.  My guess is since you're re-using the `fileName` variable but not the others something is getting mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as this:

```
List<string> files = new List<string>
{
    "Analyst's Name.txt", 
    "Group Name.txt", 
    "KB Number.txt", 
    "Return Notes.txt"
};
string sourcePath = @"\\remote location";
string targetPath = @"C:\SUPPORT\";

if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
}

for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
{
    string filePath = Path.Combine(sourcePath, files[i]);
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        File.Copy(filePath, Path.Combine(targetPath, files[i]), true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will need to be in the remote location. will let you know by tomnorow.

Comment: You don't even need a `for` you could do `foreach(var file in files)` and just use `file` everywhere there is `files[i]`.